# JavaPoet - Writing a call to a static generic method

Tags: java, annotations, auto-value, javapoet

I want to write a `CodeBlock` which is basically calling a static generic method, but the output I get with `JavaPoet` is generating compiler errors.

For example given the following auto value class:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Test<T> {
    public abstract Test1<String> o();
    public abstract T p();

    @AutoValue
    public static abstract class Test1<T> {
        public abstract T value();

        public static <T> Test1<T> create(T value) {
            return Test1.<T>builder()
                    .value(value)
                    .build();
        }

        public static <T> Builder<T> builder() {
            return new AutoValue_ValueWithOperator.Builder<>();
        }

        public static <T> Builder<T> testBuilder() {
            return builder();
        }

        @AutoValue.Builder
        public abstract static class Builder<T> {
            public abstract Builder<T> value(T value);

            public abstract Test1<T> build();
        }
    }
}
```

Now say I wanted to generate a that call to the `testBuilder` for `Test1<String>` (inside Test), I first obtain the `TypeName` by doing:

```
TypeName elementReturnType = TypeName.get(someTypeMirror);
```

Now when I do:

```
CodeBlock.of("$T.testBuilder()" + ".build()", elementReturnType);
```

It generates code that looks like:

```
Test.Test1<String>.testBuilder().build();
```

This is wrong, the correct syntax should be:

```
Test.Test1.<String>testBuilder().build();
```

Note the placement of the generic parameter...How can I accomplish this with JavaPoet? I have the correct type as you can see by the generated code, but it's just placed the generic parameter in the wrong place.

My question is, how do I add generic parameters to method call using JavaPoet `CodeBlock`?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to note that the generic type is part of the method, **not** the class, so when you write your method call, try to associate the generic with the part where you write the method call.

```
TypeName elementReturnType = TypeName.get(elementTypeMirror);
```

Assuming you have an element representing the method to call:

```
ExecutableElement method = ...;

if (methodElement.getTypeParameters().isEmpty()) {
    return CodeBlock.of("$T.$N().build()", elementReturnType, methodElement.getSimpleName());
}

String typeParams = MoreTypes
    .asDeclared(returnType)
    .getTypeArguments()
    .stream()
    .map(MoreTypes::asTypeElement)
    .map(TypeElement::getQualifiedName)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("<", ",", ">");
```

This will give you the type params which you can attach to the name of the  name of the method (`method.getSimpleName()`).